Is it possible to accurately define a structure clonable type in TypeScript
Aka define the set of all possible values that can be passed through structured clone algorithm (mdn, html spec, structuredClone).
It'd be super useful to constrain types that has to be passed through the .postMessage, structuredClone, persisted via history.pushState, or IndexedDB without the fear of encountering (and having to debug) DataCloneError. Currently I'm in the middle of using it with IndexedDB
Kinda weird that it isn't built-in into typescript via the web family of APIs (it is technically defined not in the ecmascript spec, but in the html one, although is also present in Node, Deno, Bun, jsc, etc.) window/worker.postMessage, history.pushState and IndexedDB are all super old and widely available APIs. Maybe the average 'lil JS dev doesn't use those APIs (which is a shame tbh) and there isn't that much demand for it.
Currently I have a silly definition for it like this:
type TypedArray =
  | Int8Array
  | Uint8Array
  | Uint8ClampedArray
  | Int16Array
  | Uint16Array
  | Int32Array
  | Uint32Array
  | Float32Array
  | Float64Array
  | BigInt64Array
  | BigUint64Array;

type StructureClonableError =
  | Error
  | EvalError
  | RangeError
  | ReferenceError
  | SyntaxError
  | TypeError
  | URIError;

/** @link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#webapi_types */
type WebClonableObjects =
  // | AudioData
  | Blob
  // | CropTarget
  | CryptoKey
  | DOMException
  | DOMMatrix
  | DOMMatrixReadOnly
  | DOMPoint
  | DOMPointReadOnly
  | DOMQuad
  | DOMRect
  | DOMRectReadOnly
  | File
  | FileList
  | FileSystemDirectoryHandle
  | FileSystemFileHandle
  | FileSystemHandle
  // | GPUCompilationInfo
  // | GPUCompilationMessage
  | ImageBitmap
  | ImageData
  | RTCCertificate
  | VideoFrame;

/** @link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm */
export type StructureClonable =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | bigint
  | null
  | undefined
  | StructureClonable[]
  | readonly StructureClonable[]
  | { [key: string]: StructureClonable }
  | Set<StructureClonable>
  | Map<StructureClonable, StructureClonable>
  | Date
  | ArrayBuffer
  | StructureClonableError
  | RegExp
  | TypedArray
  | WebClonableObjects;

function hasToBeStructureClonable(value: StructureClonable) { worker.postMessage(value) }
// shorthand
const htbsc = hasTobeStructureClonable

// Seems ok at first
htbsc({ foo: "bar" })                             // true positive. ok
htbsc(document)                                   // true negative. ok
htbsc({ element: document.createElement("div") }) // true negative. ok
htbsc(() => {})                                   // true negative. ok
htbsc({ [Symbol()]: "symbols are not ok" })       // true negative. ok
htbsc(new Date)                                   // true positive. ok
htbsc(new class {})                               // true negative. ok
htbsc(new Error)                                  // true positive. ok

// But there are holes
htbsc(Object.assign(new Date, { document }))      // false positive. not ok
// Non built-in prototypes are can't be serialized
htbsc(new class MyError extends Error {})         // false positive. not ok
htbsc(Object.assign([1,2,3], { document }))       // false positive. not ok
htbsc({ get foo() { return "bar" } })             // well, kinda

Also structured clone ignores property descriptors, and removes write restrictions, but that's not that important. As a part of this getter/setter functions will also be dropped, meaning the resulting object may be of different shape. I don't think you can do anything with that, as typescript can't track whether or not property is stored or defined via a getter (which also breaks type guard inference and type-system soundness, but that's beside the point)

• You seem to be using "positive" and "negative" in an unconventional way. Positive/negative mean presence/absence, not good/bad. A compiler error is a positive, and the lack of error is a negative. Please [edit] to switch to the conventional usages. • TS can't tell the difference structurally between Error and new class extends Error{} so I guess the answer is going to be "no, this is impossible"? But you've already given it a pass when it comes to getters, so maybe it's not impossible? How "accurate" is "accurate" here?

See ms/TS#29941. Sort of looks like without exact types or negated types, TS can't "accurately" represent StructuredClonable and right now they just accept any. Your type might be closer and meet your needs, but the closest to official word is that they don't seem to want to bother getting closer than any. This is also true for JSON, btw, which is more straightforward, and still TS allows any for input to JSON.stringify() and output of JSON.parse(). Does that fully address the q or am I missing something?

@jcalz I don’t believe I am misusing the notation. I classify “good” as any expected presence/lack of an error (hence “true positive”/“true negative”). Anything not expected is a “false negative”/“false positive”

@jcalz yeah I was suspecting that with structural typing it’d be impossible. Just thought someone way smarter than me figured out how to disallow extended types. Thanks for the reply anyway

You say htbsc({ foo: "bar" }) // true positive. ok for the lack of error. That's a true negative, not a positive. It's unconventional to view the lack of an error message as a positive condition. Whether or not you agree, do you understand what I'm saying? I'm not suggesting that you should use true/false differently.
